# Passing an Array into a custom Object

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object

I have a custom Object created but I can't seems to be able to pass an array into it. I'll paste my code below. The Array I'm trying to pass is the "UserProxies" one.

My object:

```
Public Class obj
    Public isPrimary As String
    Public AccountName As String
    Public DisplayName As String
    Public mail As String
    Public DistinguishName As String
    Public HomeDirectory As String
    Public EmployeeId As String
    Public Description As String
    Public HomeDrive As String
    Public ScriptPath As String
    Public telephoneNumber As String
    Public mobile As String
    Public streetAddress As String
    Public City As String
    Public Province As String
    Public Country As String
    Public postalCode As String
    Public company As String
    Public EmployeeTitle As String
    Public profilePath As String
    Public homeMDB As String
    Public legacyExchangeDN As String
    Public TargetAddress As String
    Public Enabled As String
    Public IsAccountLockedOut As String
    Public BadLogonCount As String
    Public LastBadPasswordAttempt As String
    Public LastLogon As String
    Public LastPasswordSet As String
    Public ActiveSync As String
    Public UserProxies() As String

    Sub New(isprimary As String, AccountName As String, DisplayName As String, mail As String, DistinguishName As String, HomeDirectory As String, EmployeeId As String, Description As String, HomeDrive As String, ScriptPath As String, telephoneNumber As String, mobile As String, streetAddress As String, City As String, Province As String, Country As String, postalCode As String, company As String, EmployeeTitle As String, profilePath As String, homeMDB As String, legacyExchangeDN As String, TargetAddress As String, Enabled As String, IsAccountLockedOut As String, BadLogonCount As String, LastBadPasswordAttempt As String, LastLogon As String, LastPasswordSet As String, ActiveSync As String, UserProxies() As String)
        Me.isPrimary = isprimary
        Me.AccountName = AccountName
        Me.DisplayName = DisplayName
        Me.mail = mail
        Me.DistinguishName = DistinguishName
        Me.HomeDirectory = HomeDirectory
        Me.EmployeeId = EmployeeId
        Me.Description = Description
        Me.HomeDrive = HomeDrive
        Me.ScriptPath = ScriptPath
        Me.telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber
        Me.mobile = mobile
        Me.streetAddress = streetAddress
        Me.City = City
        Me.Province = Province
        Me.Country = Country
        Me.postalCode = postalCode
        Me.company = company
        Me.EmployeeTitle = EmployeeTitle
        Me.profilePath = profilePath
        Me.homeMDB = homeMDB
        Me.legacyExchangeDN = legacyExchangeDN
        Me.TargetAddress = TargetAddress
        Me.Enabled = Enabled
        Me.IsAccountLockedOut = IsAccountLockedOut
        Me.BadLogonCount = BadLogonCount
        Me.LastBadPasswordAttempt = LastBadPasswordAttempt
        Me.LastLogon = LastLogon
        Me.LastPasswordSet = LastPasswordSet
        Me.ActiveSync = ActiveSync
        Me.UserProxies = UserProxies
    End Sub
End Class
```

Where I am filling it:

```
Public Shared UserProxies() As String 'The Public part is normal

If UserDirectory.Properties("proxyAddresses").Value IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim ProxiesObj As Object = UserDirectory.Properties("proxyAddresses").Value 'Proxy to put into object first

                Dim x As Integer = 0
                For Each Item As String In ProxiesObj
                    ReDim Preserve UserProxies(x)
                    UserProxies(x) = Item
                    x = x + 1
                Next

            End If
            UserObject.add(New obj(PrimaryAccount, AccountName, DisplayName, mail, DistinguishName, HomeDirectory, EmployeeId, Description, HomeDrive, ScriptPath, telephoneNumber, mobile, streetAddress, City, Province, Country, postalCode, company, EmployeeTitle, profilePath, homeMDB, legacyExchangeDN, TargetAddress, Enabled, IsAccountLockedOut, BadLogonCount, LastBadPasswordAttempt, LastLogon, LastPasswordSet, ActiveSync, UserProxies))
```

I get the error message when run:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

The rest is working fine. The Error message only started when I added the array into it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `ProxiesObj` actually? Have you used the debugger?

Comment: It's an object coming from the active directory object "proxyAddresses". It contain the Exchange proxy

Comment: What _type_ is it, a custom type or one of the framework?Does it implement `IEnumerable(Of String)` at all? Otherwise you can't use it in a `For.. Each`.

Comment: This object work fine. I just found that my issue was a lot more simple than that. Just an array for the output that wasn't declared big enough... Thank you though!

Comment: Ideally you should be using `.Properties("proxyAddresses")` as a `PropertyValueCollection`

Comment: Does it change something on performance?

Answer (score 1):

As i'm not allowed to comment the Question. (just 12 Rep) ;-)

The Question is when do this Exception appear, try to surround it with a try catch block for this exception or do further debugging, maybe the problem is not to pass that array to the object as the creation of the array itself.

Comment: Thanks! That actually made me found the real issue!